# transfer learning model not working on android (after training)

Tags: android, machine-learning, keras

I used Transfer Learning to learn a set of features. So used these 3 final layers on my transfer learning task.

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               6422784

---

dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0

---

## dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514

Total params: 6,423,298
Trainable params: 6,423,298
Non-trainable params: 0

---

All workout on ipythonNotebook but after making it into a .pb file and loading into Android Studio. This error occurs

> **Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: NodeDef expected inputs '' do not match 1 inputs specified; Op output:dtype; attr=value:tensor; attr=dtype:type>; NodeDef: dropout_1/cond/dropout/random_uniform/max = Constdtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor**

**The same code works on those models which have input on their first layer**
_Example: conv2d_input_1_ which was my previous task which didn't relate to transfer learning but as soon as the model changed the code didn't work. I think tensorflowAndroid wants the input layer to feed the images but our transfer learning model doesn't have the input layer to feed and is showing problem everytime
I checked the version of tensorflow and tensorflow on android and matched the version but still no luck. Could you please help me!!